# Integrating Parse Push Notifications into Xcode 7 project (Swift)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, swift2

I'm integrating Parse Push notifications into an app, and have got caught up in Swift 2.0 conversions. 
Code is:

```
if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
            let userNotificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }
```

Xcode complains that "Cannot convert value of type 'UIUserNotificationType' to expected argument type 'UIRemoteNotificationType'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code ...

app delegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

//--------------------------------------
// MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
//--------------------------------------

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("APIKEYHERE", clientKey: "CLIENTKEYHERE")

    let types:UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

//--------------------------------------
// MARK: Push Notifications
//--------------------------------------

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code, since UIRemoteNotification is deprecated, use registerUserNotificationSettigns to set the notifications settings. But remember to configure push notifications at apple's member center and at parse so it can work. You can follow this tutorial from step 1 to step 4, it's great. https://www.parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

```
if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
   let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
   application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
   application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code, though Xcode still shows warnings that UIRemoteNotificationType was deprecated in iOS 8.0

```
let types : UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound]
application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
```